# Comparing infinitives and nouns

Tags: nouns, infinitives, comparisons

I'm wondering whether it's grammatically correct to compare an infinitive with a noun using 'than'. For example:

"Does he like to play in band better than gym?" she asked?

I don't hear much usage of this comparison, but it sounds correct.

Comment: 'Better than' is less colloquial than 'more than' or 'rather than', see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=better+than%2C+more+than%2C+rather+than&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbetter%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crather%20than%3B%2Cc0). He usually went skating rather than fishing. He liked skating more than fishing. 'Liking' is quantitative - like more/like less. It is not qualitative "like better/like worse". The object is _liked_ more or liked less. The object is neither good nor bad.

Comment: No. That's like comparing chalk with cheese.

Standard US American usage might be "Does he like band better than gym". The British version would be ""Does he like the band better than the gym".

Either variety might accept “Does he like being in the band better than being in the gym" and both should see how clearly that shows the difference between “being in the band…” and “being in the gym”.